# How to wait for all child processes to terminate in C?

Tags: c, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to work on this task and i am very new to it. This task requires me to create direct child processes depending on the number of full path unix command from the command line argument in C.

E.G

```
./main.c /bin/uname 
(create 1 fork)

./main.c /bin/uname /bin/ls
(create 2 forks)
etc
```

After each child process has been executed the parent process will display "Command %s has been completed successfully" or "Command %s has not been completed successfully".

So this is where my question comes in:

1. Is it because of the for loop, the statement "all good, bye bye!\n" prints out after each command is executed? if so, why doesn't the wait call work?
2. Is the sleep call working? because when running the first unix command, the next one is immediately printed out after the first command.
3. How do I wait for **all** the child processes to terminate and print out "all done, bye-bye!"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void CreateChildren(int argCounter, char *argVector[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CreateChildren(argc,argv);
    
    return 0;
}

void CreateChildren(int argCounter, char *argVector[])
{
    int counter = 1;
    pid_t pid;
    

    printf("Program name is: %s\n\n", argVector[0]);

    if(argCounter == 1)
    {
        printf("No extra command line\n");
    }

    if(argCounter >= 2)
    {
        
        for(counter;counter < argCounter; counter++)
        {
            //create child process each time the counter increases
            pid = fork();
            
            if(pid < 0)
            {
                printf("Unable to create child process\n");
                exit(1);
            }else
                if(pid == 0)
                {
                    //child process. execute the command
                    execl(argVector[counter], argVector[counter], (char *)0);
                    sleep(100);
                    exit(0);
                }else
                {
                    //parent process
                    //wait will pass a pointer to an int. Returns a the process ID of the child process
                    //if the child pid is equals to the status of the wait then child process id is ok else it will return -1

                    int status;
                    if(pid == wait(&status))
                    {
                        printf("Command %s has completed successfully\n\n",argVector[counter]);
                    }else
                        printf("Command %s has NOT completed successfully\n\n", argVector[counter]);

                       
                    wait(&status);
                    printf("all good, bye-bye!\n");           
                }    
        }
    }

    
}
```

Command line argument to execute the program:

```
./main.c /bin/hostname /bin/date /bin/ls /bin/ps /bin/uname
```

Actual output:

```
Program name is: ./main.c

iconikeu-virtual-machine

Command /bin/hostname has completed successfully

all good, bye-bye!

Tue 21 Feb 2023 05:48:37 PM +08

Command /bin/date has completed successfully

all good, bye-bye!

assignment1  assignment1.c  cmds.txt  main.c

Command /bin/ls has completed successfully

all good, bye-bye!

    PID TTY          TIME CMD
  77518 pts/3    00:00:01 bash
 102786 pts/3    08:05:12 sh
 115809 pts/3    00:00:00 main.c
 115813 pts/3    00:00:00 ps

Command /bin/ps has completed successfully

all good, bye-bye!

Linux

Command /bin/uname has completed successfully

all good, bye-bye!
```

Expected output:

```
Program name is: ./main.c

iconikeu-virtual-machine

Command /bin/hostname has completed successfully


Tue 21 Feb 2023 05:48:37 PM +08

Command /bin/date has completed successfully


assignment1  assignment1.c  cmds.txt  main.c

Command /bin/ls has completed successfully


    PID TTY          TIME CMD
  77518 pts/3    00:00:01 bash
 102786 pts/3    08:05:12 sh
 115809 pts/3    00:00:00 main.c
 115813 pts/3    00:00:00 ps

Command /bin/ps has completed successfully


Linux

Command /bin/uname has completed successfully

all good, bye-bye!
```

Comment: Keep track of all started child-processes and their PID's, then check against what [`wait`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) returns?

Comment: `/main.c /bin/uname /bin/ls` You run C files as command? Normally you don't run C files but compile them and the resulting exectuable doesn't have .c suffix.

Comment: @Gerhardh Glad you told me about it. I didn't know that the executable file doesn't have .c suffix. Thank you

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude alright, ill have a go at it

Comment: That's not a big deal but if you name your executable .c you risk accidentally overwriting your source file. And we also saw questions here where the authors tried to execute the C file without compiling. (I did not assume that in this question.)

Answer (score 0):

The `printf("all good, bye-bye!\n");` instruction is *inside* the loop, when it should be *outside*. With

```
                    ...
                    if(pid == wait(&status))
                    {
                        printf("Command %s has completed successfully\n\n",argVector[counter]);
                    }else
                        printf("Command %s has NOT completed successfully\n\n", argVector[counter]);


                }
        }
        printf("all good, bye-bye!\n");
    }
}
```

I correctly get:

```
Program name is: ./main

my_hostname
Command /bin/hostname has completed successfully

Tue Feb 21 11:30:14 CET 2023
Command /bin/date has completed successfully

main main.c
Command /bin/ls has completed successfully

  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    9 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
  119 pts/0    00:00:00 main
  123 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
Command /bin/ps has completed successfully

Linux
Command /bin/uname has completed successfully

all good, bye-bye!
```

But beware, as you did not keep track of possible failure inside the loop, this code will end with `all good` even if some commands were not successful...

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is it because of the for loop, the statement "all good, bye bye!\n" prints out after each command is executed? If so, why doesn't the wait call work?

You are waiting for each child process to complete before creating the next one.

```
int status;
if(pid == wait(&status))
```

The second call to `wait` and the call to `printf` to display an exit message are within the loop.

```
wait(&status);
printf("all good, bye-bye!\n");
```

This second call to `wait` returns immediately, and `errno` is set to `ECHILD` as there are no unwaited-for children at this time. The message is printed once for each child process.

---

> 2. Is the sleep call working? because when running the first unix command, the next one is immediately printed out after the first command.

When an `exec*` function is successful, it **never** returns, as the process image is completely replaced.

```
execl(argVector[counter], argVector[counter], (char *)0);
sleep(100);
exit(0);
```

The call to `sleep` only executes in the event that `execl` *fails*.

If you want to sleep between creating processes, it should be done in the parent process before/after forking, or in the child process before calling `exec*` (only with your current wait scheme, see below).

---

> 3. How do I wait for **all** the child process to terminate and print out "all done, bye-bye!"?

This depends.

As stated previously, you currently *do* wait for every child process to terminate - you just do it one-by-one, immediately after forking each process. No two processes can run at the same time. If this is desired, simply move the call to `printf` outside the loop.

If you instead want the processes to run at the same time, you should call `wait` in a separate loop, after the process creation loop.

A cursory example of the latter:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s COMMAND [COMMAND2] [..]\n", *argv);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    argc--;
    argv++;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if (-1 == pid) {
            fprintf(stderr, "fork %s: %s\n", argv[i], strerror(errno));
            continue;
        }

        if (0 == pid) {
            execlp(argv[i], argv[i], (char *) NULL);
            fprintf(stderr, "exec %s: %s\n", argv[i], strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    while ((pid = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("Child <%ld> exited with status %d\n",
                (long) pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));

    puts("Complete. Goodbye.");
}
```

```
$ ./a.out date ls uname
Tue 21 Feb 2023 09:41:19 AM AST
Linux
a.out  exec.c
Child <2748> exited with status 0
Child <2750> exited with status 0
Child <2749> exited with status 0
Complete. Goodbye.
```